# How to automatically fill the fields of a form in a webview?

Tags: java, android, webview, android-webview

Basically, i want to fill a field on the paypal register form.
Here's my code:

```
final String paypal_url = "https://www.paypal.com/welcome/signup/#/email_password";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    fillField();

}

private void fillField() {
    WebView webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
    webView.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
    webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webView.loadUrl(paypal_url);

    webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
        @Override
        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
            super.onPageFinished(view, url);

            view.loadUrl("javascript:document.getElementById('paypalAccountData_firstName').value = 'test';");

        }

    });

}
```

And this is the result: it loads the page and then displays this:

[image: this]

I had already tried almost every solution on this site, without success (the field was not filled).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to wait the entire web page loads, including its content (`id="paypalAccountData_firstName"`)
So you should change

```
view.loadUrl("javascript:document.getElementById('paypalAccountData_firstName').value = 'test';");
```

to

```
view.loadUrl( "javascript:window.onload= (function(){ document.getElementById('paypalAccountData_firstName').value = 'test';})();");
```

Comment: This is not working. It displays the page without filling the field.

Comment: You want to auto fill this tag paypalAccountData_firstName right? Since I encounter a redirection of this page due to my country so I’m not sure what class name exist in the page

Comment: Yes. What redirection? Using the code i posted, if i change the id "paypalAccountData_firstName" with another random string (obv, not another id) it displays the page without filling the field, so only with the right id name it does something even if it is not what i want. So i think the problem is not the id.

Comment: Okay, i found the problem. Thanks very much for your help.

Answer (score 1):

So, the problem was Paypal's redirection. The code Paul posted works, but only if it is loaded the US version of the site.
Changes:

```
final String paypal_url = "https://www.paypal.com/us/signup/account";
```

And

```
view.loadUrl( "javascript:window.onload= (function(){ document.getElementById('paypalAccountData_firstName').value = 'test';})();");
```